# Как добавить функцию к уже существующему типу данных?

Tags: python, функции, переменные

Допустим, есть переменная `x = 1`. Как создать функцию `self.plus(num)`, которая будет прибавлять к числу `self` (в данном случае `x`) число `num` и возвращать результат?

Comment: К встроенным типам - никак

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для реализации твоей задумки можно использовать -  **концепцию классов**.

Вот пример кода:

```py
class MyInt(int):
    def plus(self, num):
        return self + num

x = MyInt(1)
result = x.plus(2)
print(result)  # Выведет: 3
```

## Как работает код:

Я создал класс `MyInt`, который наследуется от встроенного типа `int`. Далее  добавил функцию `plus`, которая принимает число `num` и прибавляет его к значению объекта `self` (в данном случае x). Возвращенный результат сохраняется в переменной `result` и выводится на экран.

Comment: Здесь создаётся новый тип, а не меняется существующий